# Is there a way for me to allow users to save an image to their iOS camera roll from my website?

Tags: ios, download, instagram, instagram-api

I have users who want to copy images of themselves from my website (we make trading cards for youth athletes) to share on Instagram.

I know there isn't a way to directly share images on instagram, but is there a way for me to allow people browsing on their iOS device to save an image from my website to their camera roll so they can then share the image on Instagram?

Comment: Just put it on your web site? They should be able to save any image in a normal img tag

Comment: I guess they could just click and hold...what I'm being asked for is a button that would save the image with one click.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure whether that's possible!

Comment: Is your website built using HTML5?